# How to return a value and a promise from a function at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm doing something like this

```
var command1;
var command2;

var fn = function(param) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  var command = spawn(..., [
    ... passing different arguments based on param ...
  ]);
  ...
  command.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    if (/... if process started successfully .../.test(data)) {
      deferred.resolve();
    }
  });
  ...
  if (param === 'command1') {
     command1 = command;
  } else {
     command2 = command;
  }
  return deferred.promise;
};

Q.all([
  fn('command1'),
  fn('command2')
]);
```

and later on I'm calling `command1.kill()` and `command2.kill()`. I thought about passing `command` to `resolve`, but then it may never be called. I could pass `command` to `reject` also, so that I could call `kill` there if something goes wrong, but that feels weird.

How do I return `command` and the promise as well to the caller in an idiomatic way? Without the conditional part in `fn`. What are the possibilities?

I also thought about ES6's deconstructing assignment feature, but consider the following

```
  ...
  return [command, deferred.promise];
}

[command1, promiseCommand1] = fn('command1');
[command2, promiseCommand2] = fn('command2');

Q.all([
  promise1,
  promise2.then(Q.all([
    promiseCommand1,
    promiseCommand2    
  ])
]);
```

but this fails (at least in my particular case, where the commands should wait until `promise2` is resolved), because the processes are already on their way when I pass `promiseCommand1` and `promiseCommand2` to `Q.all`.

<sub>Not sure if I used the correct deconstructing assignment syntax.</sub>

Just popped into my mind

```
var command1;
var command2;

var fn = function(param, callback) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  var command = spawn(..., [...]);
  ...
  callback(command);
  return deferred.promise; 
};

Q.all([
  fn('command1', function(command) {
    command1 = command;
  }),
  fn('command1', function(command) {
    command2 = command;
  })
]);
```

Any other way?

## Update

Since yesterday I've figured out how could I might use a deconstructing assignment (still not sure on the syntax)

```
Q.all([
  promise1,
  promise2.then(function() {
    [command1, promiseCommand1] = fn('command1');
    [command2, promiseCommand2] = fn('command2');    
    return Q.all([
      promiseCommand1,
      promiseCommand2    
    ]);
  })
]);
```

this way the commands will only be executed after `promise2` is resolved.

## Solution

Based on [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35617029/433835) and my previous update I came up with this

```
  command.promise = deferred.promise;
  return command;
};

Q.all([
  promise1,
  promise2.then(function() {
    command1 = fn('command1');
    command2 = fn('command2');    
    return Q.all([command1.promise, command2.promise]);
  })
]);
```

Works and seems to be a concise solution for me. I don't want to rely on ES6 for the deconstructing assignment. Also, I don't think I can use the feature to assign one value to a variable declared outside of the scope and assign the other in the local scope concisely. Returning

```
return {
  command: command,
  promise: deferred.promise
};
```

is also a possible solution, but less concise.

```
Q.all([
  promise1,
  promise2.then(function() {
    var result1 = fn('command1');
    var result2 = fn('command2');
    command1 = result1.command;
    command2 = result2.command;   
    return Q.all([result1.promise, result2.promise]);
  })
]);
```

## Correction

In the comment section in the accepted answer I was advised to call `reject` in `fn` to prevent my code hang forever because of a pending promise. I've solved this with the following

```
  command.promise = deferred.promise.timeout(...);
  return command;
};
```

Using `timeout` will return the same promise, however if the promise is not resolved in given timeout value the promise will be rejected automatically.

Comment: the problem with `promise2.then(Q.all([` is that the argument(s) to `.then` **MUST** be function(s) - otherwise they are effectively ignored

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, my example was off. However it was educational :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should end up with something useful by turning your "pass command to reject" on its head. In other words, reject in response to a `kill()` command.

The trouble, as you know, is that `fn()` should return a promise, and a promise doesn't naturally convey the corresponding command's `.kill()` method. However javascript allows the dynamic attachment of properties, including functions (as methods), to objects. Therefore adding a `.kill()` method is simple.

```
var fn = function(param) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var command = spawn(..., [
        ... passing different arguments based on param ...
    ]);
    ...
    command.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        if (/... if process started successfully .../.test(data)) {
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    });
    ...
    var promise = deferred.promise;
    // Now monkey-patch the promise with a .kill() method that fronts for command.kill() AND rejects the Deferred.
    promise.kill = function() {
        command.kill();
        deferred.reject(new Error('killed')); // for a more specific error message, augment 'killed' with something unique derived from `param`. 
    }
    return promise;
};

var promise1 = fn('command1');
var promise2 = fn('command2');

Q.all([promise1, promise2]).spread(...).catch(...);
```

`promise1.kill()` or `promise2.kill()` will give rise to "killed" appearing as `error.message` in the catch handler.

The two kills can be called as appropriate, for example ...

```
if(...) {
    promise1.kill();
}
if(...) {
    promise2.kill();
}
```

Alternatively, the `.kill()` methods will also detach cleanly without needing to `.bind()`, for example :

```
doSomethingAsync(...).then(...).catch(promise1.kill);
doSomethingElseAsync(...).then(...).catch(promise2.kill);
```

Note that `fn()` will work for any number of calls without the need for outer vars `command1`, `command2` etc.

Comment: Nice thinking, however I don't think I can do this. I haven't mentioned it in the question (thought it doesn't matter, but it does actually), but I'm launching the commands in an Protractor integration test's `beforeLaunch` function and I'm calling `kill` in `afterLaunch`. I'm returning from `beforeLaunch` with a promise to delay the start of tests until my processes are up and running. In `afterLaunch` the *chain* can't be accessed anymore (at least, I think can't access it).

Comment: Just came to me. The solution for me is almost the same thing you've proposed, but instead patching `kill` on the `promise` I patched a `promise` on the `ChildProcess` object. I'll update my answer to include the solution. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Whichever way round you do the patching, I still think you need a mechanism to reject the Deferred when .kill() is called.  Otherwise your Promise.all([..., ...]) will remain "pending" after a kill command has been issued.

Comment: If I ever get to call `kill` on the `ChildProcess` that means `resolve` was called. If it haven't been called, then either I already called `reject` listening on the 'error' event of the process, or ... I was not able to decide listening on `stdout` and `stderr` if I should call `reject`. If `resolve` is never called Protractor will timeout and fail the whole test with an error, so that's fine by me.

Comment: As it stands, `deferred.reject();` doesn't appear in `fn()`, therefore the promise returned by `fn()` is not subject to a timeout.

Comment: I do call `reject` in my actual node (not appears in the example sorry) in `process.on('error', ...)`. If the command I'm running is correct then `resolve` will be called 99.99% of the times. If not, well shit :)

Comment: That't looks a whole lot better. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 1):

You can return an array and then use `promise.spread` method.

https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination

```
.then(function () {
    return [command, promise];
})
.spread(function (command, promise) {
});
```

Comment: If I return `[command, deferred.promise];` from `fn` then the function won't return a promise, but an array which second element is a promise. To use `spread` I would have to resolve to an array, no? `deferred.resolve([...])` Then would I be able to use `spread`. Anyway, I don't get your point sorry. Can you elaborate?